# bash grep file not found

Tags: bash, grep

I wish to apply some commands based on a grep search I do `grep -l "If you wish to distribute" *.pdf` and I see the files I want to process but with the following bash script the files are not processed:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
text1="If you wish to distribute"  #Science papers

# Originally: grep -l "text1" \*.pdf |

grep -l "$text1" *.pdf |
while IFS="" read -r -d "" file; do
  noext="${file%\.*}"
  pdftk "$file" cat 2-end output "$noext".tmp 
  mv -f "$noext".tmp "$file"
done
```

and the output is

```
+ IFS=
+ grep -l 'If you wish to distribute' project_latex.pdf 'Science 2003 Metapopulation Persistence with Age-Dependent Disturbance or Succession.pdf' 'Science 2006 A Keystone Mutualism Drives Pattern in a Power Function.pdf' short-math-guide.pdf Test.pdf
+ read -r -d '' file
```

Comment: does this work if you drop the `-d ""` portion of the read command?

Answer (score 3):

The backslash in front of the `*` means that `grep` is told to scan `*.pdf` (a single file name with an asterisk as the first character).  Remember, the shell does metacharacter expansions; commands do not.

Remove the backslash to give `grep` a list of all the PDF files.

Comment: Thanks, the grep part seems to be working but pdftk don't get the files.

Comment: What is the purpose of the decorations on and around `read`?  I'd expect to use simply `while read file; do ...`.  Does that help at all?  Do you get a list of file names from the `grep` command?  Do any of the PDF files contain that long string without any Postscript mark up around the words?

Comment: @LeonardoSaravia: Did you do what Marc B suggested too?

Comment: @doubleDown: Judging from the changed trace output and revised `grep` line in the question, the answer's yes.

Comment: Yes you are right @JonathanLeffler a simple `read` solved it, and in  science papers that long string works,

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -l "text1" \*.pdf |
```

isn't doing anything except searching pdfs for the literal text `text1`. You forgot the `$` to make it a variable:

```
grep -l "$text1" \*.pdf |
         ^---
```

Answer (score 1):

as i mentioned in my comment, try dropping the `-d ''` argument to read.

Comment: All the three answers contribute to the solution, Thanks!